# Regex to match variable list of entries

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to understand how I might be able to craft a regex pattern to match a variable length list of sparse values in something that already looks a bit like a dictionary.

The input string is of the form:

```
log = """
  My sensors:
    Sensor 0:       11.000 °C
    Sensor 1:       12.000 °C
    Sensor 2:       13.250 °C
"""
log = """
  My sensors:
    Sensor 1:       14.375 °C
    Sensor 3:       15.625 °C
"""
```

So the output that I'm after is:

```
{
  0: 11.000,
  1: 12.000,
  2: 13.250
}
```

and

```
{
 1: 14.375,
 3: 15.625
}
```

The closest I can get is to reasonably parse an individual sensor line as I loop over lines of the log:

```
import re

d = {}
pattern = "[\S\s]*Sensor (?P<sensor_index>\d+):       (?P<value>\d+\.\d+) °C[\S\s]*"
for line in log:
  match = re.findall(pattern, line)
  if match:
    matches = match.groupdict()
    d[matches['sensor_index']] = matches['value']

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to parse the whole strung. Split it into lines and parse each line separately:

```
lines = [re.findall("Sensor (\d+):\s+(\d+\.\d+) °C", line) 
          for line in log.split("\n")]
d = {int(pair[0][0]): float(pair[0][1]) 
     for pair in lines if pair}
#{0: 11.0, 1: 12.0, 2: 13.25}
```